# Firebase putFile two files to the same reference

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

If you initiate two uploads to the same reference using Firebase's `putFile(...)` how is this resolved?

Say for example, if I send two requests via putFile:

> putFile(from: A, metadata: ...)

And immediately after,

> putFile(from: B, metadata: ...)

will B always be the file that ends up in firebase? Or will it be inconsistent which file ends up  at the reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the last write to be completed "wins", so the first one that completes will be overwritten.